# Dose anyone know of a good problem/exercise book to go along with and supplement kiselev geometry 1&2

Tags: geometry, book-recommendation

Hi Ive just finished my a levels in maths, further maths and physics and i find myself board already my weakest topic in maths is geometry and frankly i am awful at it i want rectify this by learning geometry properly as i was not taught a lot of geometry due to covid effecting my education, I was recommended  kiselev geometry 1&2 but find the lack of problems concerning as i feel the best way to learn math properly is to do a lot of problems on a topic after learning the theory i found this approach helpful when i did my alevels and want to do the same thing for self study so i was just wondering if anyone knows of a good problem/exercise book to go along with and supplement kiselev geometry 1&2 :any other tips/recommendations on how to approach geometry will be helpful as my brain just dose not like it for some reason idk why and it annoys me because i recognize the usefulness of geometry in other parts of math and physics and really want to learn it properly